# Why isn't Star Trek: Discovery produced in 4K?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

*Star Trek: Discovery* is a modern TV show and yet it's produced in 2K HDR. Yes, HDR makes it beautiful, but I don't find it as detailed as 4K videos.

Why isn't *Star Trek: Discovery* produced in 4K HDR?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**It was made for a channel that doesn't support 4K**

Star Trek:Discovery was originally made for CBS All Access, although it's on Netflix in many countries outside of the USA. Unlike Netflix, Amazon Prime, and many other streaming services, CBS All Access [does not support 4K streams](https://www.digitaltrends.com/buying-guides/what-is-cbs-all-access/) and, if internet reports on its quality are to be believed, appears to run its streams at much lower bandwidth even in normal HD.

Since it was made specifically for a service that doesn't support 4K, the producers could save money by using cameras and CGI targetted at a lower resolution.

Answer (score 6):

The show was filmed on [Arri Alexa XT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arri_Alexa#Alexa_XT) cameras for [various](https://www.promoviemaker.net/inspiration/starring-role/) [reasons](https://www.digitalcinemareport.com/article/star-trek-gets-new-look).
The maximum image quality that can be yielded from these cameras is 3.2K, hence the lack of a 4K or 8K option for viewers.

Note that the show was intended to be broadcast on its own internet streaming channel, so having the show be in 4K (or 8K) is basically unnecessary since the average viewer couldn't possibly tell the difference.

[image]

Comment: Your last paragraph doesn't make sense. I watch *Star Trek: Discovery* over Internet (Netflix) and yet I can tell the difference.

Comment: Must people don't care and can't tell the difference. If you're in the small minority that do care (and claim to be able to tell the difference) then bully for you.

Comment: You can easily spot the difference on big screens. And, don't generalize anything without having solid data. Netflix sells its Ultra 4K subscription tier pretty well.

Comment: @UmbrellaCorporation - Most people don't have a screen big enough to show the difference. Netflix 4K subscription sells to a tiny proportion of ifs customers.

Comment: @UmbrellaCorporation Except that most people either don’t have big enough screens, or have them set up in such a way that they can’t tell (for example, they have a viewing distance that is long enough that the difference is not noticable). Also, the Ultra 4k subscription tier on Netflix sells at least as much because of the fact that it allows the most devices to be simultaneously active (this is important if it’s a family account) as the 4k support.

Comment: @Valorum / Austin Hemmelgarn : Can you please show some more objective data that 4K doesn't matter? With massive investments in bandwidth, storage and technology or the skip, your conclusion kinda needs a bit of support. Especially since the difference at higher bitrates and commonly sold TV sizes currently is visible.

Comment: @Valorum: 4K is easily detectable to the untrained eye  on a 50” screen unless you are standing well away from it.

Comment: Saying the camera can't do it didn't answer the question,  it just makes it "so why use that camera".

Comment: @JackAidley If you follow the links already provided, you can see they are heavily invested in those cameras.  So your criticism should not be at the answer or even the producers, but at the camera manufacturer for not having a 4K/8K version of it that drops into their existing setup.

Comment: @JackAidley - It's a case of tail-wag-dog. They're a streaming service, so the goal is to limit the cost of streaming, which means filming at a resolution that limits bandwidth

Comment: Most people probably wouldn't be able to tell the difference between 4k and 8k unless they had a massive screen (probably 85-90"+)

Comment: @Valorum That seems like the actual answer: it was made for a streaming service that does not support 4K. The camera stuff and the (false) claim consumers can't tell the difference are red herrings.

Comment: Is there any reason why the anamorphic lenses chosen should not be compatible with using 4K cameras? Since if there is none, the stylistic choices (esp. for season 2) do not forbid using 4k and the CBS All Access network not supporting 4k may be more important as a reason.